# In Sencha Touch, how do I detect when store has loaded and list is ready to be shown

Tags: listview, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, store

I have a list that is tied to a store. I'm waiting for the store load before I show the list with animation whose duration is 500ms. The first time I load the list, even though I wait for the store to lead, the list always comes up first and then the the data appears abruptly. I'd like to wait until the list is completely ready before opening it up using show(). What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback in [load](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load) method of store. One more method is to add listeners to 'load' and 'beforeload' events of store.

Comment: I am calling back on load – it didn't have the effect. I think I'm getting desired result with order: 'after'. Like so: 
    
myList.getStore().on({
    single: true,
    order: 'after',
    load: function(){
        // show the list
    }
});
myList.getStore().load();